# ListPlot with PlotMarkers -> None

Tags: plotting

I'd like a pin plot with no pinheads (i.e., no plot markers).  While there are other ways to get the effect I want, I expected the following to work:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> None]
```

[image]

But the result still includes (smaller) plot markers.  How does one turn off the plot markers?

Comment: I agree that what you tried should work. In the meantime, there are plenty of ways to workaround this, one might be `ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[Opacity[0]]}]`

Answer (score 7):

Some simple ways to do it.

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> Null]

ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> ""]

ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> Graphics[]]
```

All three give

[image: plot]

Comment: As I noted in the question, there are many workarounds.  The latter two set `PlotMarkers` to something innocuous but do not actually turn them off. But your first suggestion roughly answers my question, but I'm not quite sure what it means to set `PlotMarkers->Null`.  It looks like Mma creates an inset with a `Null` in it so that nothing gets printed?  And, why doesn't `PlotMarkers->None` just turn off the whole mechanism?  (Bug or feature?)

Comment: In v.12.3, the first solution now uses the word `Null` as a PlotMarker.

Comment: And don't try `PlotMarkers -> Nothing` unless you want to see some ugly error messages and output!

Answer (score 7):

Too easy with `PlotStyle`:

```
ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]]
```